# How to put an out folder of nextjs to a nginx using Docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js, docker-compose

I try to pass nextjs out folder to nginx but fails. This is my docker compose file.

```
version: "3"

services:
  nextjs:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - staticbuild:/out

  nestjs:
    build:
      context: ./back
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./back/.env

  nginx-proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - staticbuild:/usr/share/nginx/html

volumes:
  staticbuild:
```

I can see the out folder if I go to the terminal of the running next js container. But in nginx, its welcome page is served. This is my nginx.conf.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name acme.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://nextjs:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

if I do this in nginx Dockerfile, it serves out folder.

```
COPY where_next_located/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

But with this compose file, somehow the welcome page appears. Even though I changed staticbuild:/usr/share/nginx/html to staticbuild:/app/public, I can still see the page inside app/public. I can't understand why this is happening and how to serve contets of staticbuild:/out from nginx ?

Comment: Is the `proxy_pass` line correct; is the `nextjs` (`client`) container actually used for anything other than its build output?  I might `COPY` the content into the proxy image (maybe via a multi-stage build) and remove the volume, and that might leave the other container completely unused and you can then delete it.

Comment: The client container runs as a server not just for the build. I decided to build next project again inside nginx Dockerfile. that works for me. Thanks for the comment.